# Cannot execute nor locate sublime-text-3 after installing via ssh terminal

Tags: 14.04, sublime-text

I installed sublime-text-3 via ssh terminal using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

I am not able to execute nor locate the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you proceeded, Sublime text editor should be installed and working.

Try using the command `subl` on the terminal, to see if it will open Sublime.

Comment: it says /usr/bin/subl: 2: exec: /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text: not found

Answer (score 1):

I installed Sublime with the same commands you mentioned and then clicked on the Ubuntu launcher icon (top left) and simply typed "sublime", Ubuntu found it for me:

[image]